# Require a method of an instantiated class to be called

Tags: java, compiler-errors, requirements

Let's say I have this code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void doSomething(int value) {

    }
}
public class MyNewClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to get a compiler error that `doSomething(int)` from `MyClass` has not been called in `MyNewClass`? I know realistically you would put that method in the constructor but this question is out of curiosity.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your use case for this? Look at factory methods and private constructors if additional set up is needed after instantiation.

Comment: Using plain Java, no. You can get something like this using aspect programming e.g. [aspectj](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/)

Comment: Java doesn't care what methods you don't call.

Comment: You'd probably have to [use custom annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205261/how-to-create-custom-annotation-with-code-behind) to enforce something like this

Comment: @Paul Bellora Well I was thinking along the lines of some information you would need for a part of a class to work but that you would not necessarely have when you instantiate it. But yeah, after thinking about it for a while, I can't come up with a specific scenario where you would absolutely need this. That's why I put out of curiosity.

Comment: The answers given are quite interesting and diverse. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I found a situation where this would be very useful. In android, onActivityResult is only available to an activity. If I make a separate class that does not extend/implement onActivityResult, I would have to call (using the example above) doSomething(int value), otherwise the class will not do it's job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can come to this is using code coverage tools. Providing you have a full set of unit tests, they will allow you to identify, for example, which methods are never called. I can't recommend one library in particular but there are plenty available.