# Can we add annotation to the method to print log before method start and end executing in java

Tags: java, aop

Example:

```
@LogMethod
void getSum(a,b){
   return a+b
}
```

before method start executing

```
   method started
```

after method executed

```
   method end
```

I am not using spring in my project so can not used spring-aop

Comment: @KnockingHeads he specifically states he doesn't use Spring

Comment: https://fw-geekycoder.blogspot.com/2010/05/aspectj-and-aspectj-without-spring.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205261/how-to-create-custom-annotation-with-code-behind